# Plotting graph for simple harmonic motion experiment

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics

I am asked to plot a curve for a graph given the follow kg table and information:

[image]

Here is my attempt. Does the curve look correct ? And if not could you explain where I went wrong.

[image]

Comment: Looks good but I would emphasize the flat spots around the maxima at $s=5$.  You have a maximum there, so the derivative goes to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your curve looks correct. For future problems like this, I recommend using an online graphing calculator, like [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator). I plotted these points for you and found a fitted cosine curve [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/1pesw5hkkl).

[image]